# How to upgrade libxnvctrl0?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

If I run

```bsh
sudo apt update
```

I get a message ending with

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done         
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

If I then run

```
apt list --upgradable
```

I get

```
Listing... Done
libxnvctrl0/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
N: There are 15 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this upgrade. If I do

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then reboot, then

```
apt list --upgradable
```

still shows

```
Listing... Done
libxnvctrl0/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
N: There are 15 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

How can I upgrade this package?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. It evolved into the following once I updated cuda: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247621/upgraded-nvidia-packages-not-persistent