# Mate ubuntu 18.04 LTS, package libxnvctrl0 not upgradable

Tags: 18.04, apt, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

When trying to update my system, one package,
libxnvctrl0, seems to be kept as outdated even though I did a  `sudo apt update` previously:

```
user@user-workstation:~$ sudo apt list  --upgradable
En train de lister... Fait
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
N: Il y a des versions supplémentaires 15. Veuillez utiliser l'opérande « -a » pour les voir.
```

I saw that I am not the only one encountering this issue:
[package_libxnvctrl0_not_upgradable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247621/upgraded-nvidia-packages-not-persistent).
The only solution which has been proposed is to deactivate all nvidia dev repos:

```
user@ser-workstation:~$ grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* |  grep "nvidia"
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list:deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list.save:deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-machine-learning.list:deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-machine-learning.list.save:deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
```

Here are some aditionnal output:

```
user@user-workstation$  apt-cache policy libxnvctrl0
libxnvctrl0:
  Installé : 450.36.06-0ubuntu1
  Candidat : 450.36.06-0ubuntu1
 Table de version :
     450.36.06-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
 *** 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     440.64.00-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     440.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     440.33.01-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     418.87.01-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     418.87.00-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     418.67-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     418.40.04-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     418.39-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     410.129-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     410.104-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     410.79-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     410.72-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     410.48-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
     390.42-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

```
user@user-workstation:texmf$ sudo apt list  --upgradable -a

En train de lister... Fait
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libxnvctrl0/now 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installé, pouvant être mis à jour vers : 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 440.64.00-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/bionic-updates 440.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 440.33.01-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 418.87.01-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 418.87.00-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 418.67-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 418.40.04-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 418.39-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 410.129-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 410.104-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 410.79-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 410.72-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 410.48-0ubuntu1 amd64
libxnvctrl0/bionic 390.42-0ubuntu1 amd64
```

I am still experiencing the confusion:

```
user@user-workstation$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxnvctrl0=450.36.06-0ubuntu1
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  libxnvctrl0
1 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/21,3 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
(Lecture de la base de données... 415783 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libxnvctrl0_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libxnvctrl0:amd64 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) sur (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Paramétrage de libxnvctrl0:amd64 (450.36.06-0ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

```
user@user-workstation$ sudo list --upgradable
sudo: list : commande introuvable
user@user-workstation:texmf$ sudo apt list --upgradable
En train de lister... Fait
libxnvctrl0/inconnu 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [pouvant être mis à jour depuis : 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
N: Il y a des versions supplémentaires 15. Veuillez utiliser l'opérande « -a » pour les voir.
```

Is there a smarter way to solve this?

Could anyone provide me some informations as to what is currently going on with this package?
Is there a bug which has been officially open?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libxnvctrl0` to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just updated my question with  the output of ```apt-cache policy libxnvctrl0```

Comment: To be completely sure what is going, please add also output of `sudo apt list  --upgradable -a` to the question.

Comment: Ok, I have added the output. "Inconnu" means "unknown" in english

Comment: I am still confused, you can have a look at my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-cache policy libxnvctrl0` showed us that there are two sources for the latest *450.36.06-0ubuntu1* version. One is already installed, one is a candidate for installation.

You can specify that you want to reinstall latest version with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxnvctrl0=450.36.06-0ubuntu1
```

to inform APT that you are installing latest version. It will remove confusion, I hope.

Comment: I am still experiencing the confusion:

```